# consume a web service from a c++ windows service application

Tags: c++, web-services, service, wsdl, webmethod

I am trying to consume a c# web service in a c++ windows service application. I first wrote a c++ VCL forms app and consumed the web service using WSDL importer. This worked perfectly and gave me access to all the web methods. Then I wrote the c++ service application and again used WSDL importer to import the web service. The c++ service compiles and I can install the service, but as soon as I use any of the web methods the service hangs.

I cannot find any information online regarding service applications and web services - is it even possible to import a web service to a windows service application? Can anyone explain if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. Just to clarify I consumed a c# asmx web service inside a c++ windows service using WSDL. The only reason it didn't work was because I forgot to initialize the COM subsystem for the thread. I added the following line to my code and it now works perfectly: CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);